# Is getResourceAsStream() thread-safe?

Tags: java

I need to read a properties file containing some configuration data in a JSF web application.

Right now the code looks like this

```
 private Properties getConfig() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");

        try {
        properties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Error while reading config properties", e);
        }

    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        }
    }

    return properties;
 }
```

Is it safe to do it this way or can I run into concurrency issues when multiple threads are calling getConfig()?

Comment: I am not sure it is thread safe or not but normally in such a case I use a single tone Config class in which I load property file once and then access it where ever I want. This is possible in case where no one gonna change property file after deployment.

Comment: Yes, i used some Singleton approach for this in the first place. But the requirement is that the file can be changed any time.

Comment: and that why I mentioned in my comment that *This is possible in case where no one gonna change property file after deployment.*

Comment: @Harry You're right and I did not meant to criticize your commment. I just wanted to point out why I had to change the singleton approach which was thread safe to this solution, where I am not sure about thread safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that should be perfectly safe. I can't see any concurrency issues in there.

However, the exception handling might not be ideal - is it valid to return an empty properties object if you fail to load the config, or should you propagate the exception out of `getConfig()`? Up to you, really....